# PHP LDAP: How to search if user is in group?

Tags: php, ldap

How can i check if a user is part of a group using php_ldap module?

I'm completely new to ldap and hence a bit confused...

With googling I've come up with this so far:

```
$ds=ldap_connect($ldapHost, $ldapPort);
if ($ds) {
    $r=ldap_bind($ds, $ldapRdn, $ldapPassword);
    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=" . $uid . ")";
    $attr = array("memberof");
    $result = ldap_search($ds, $ldapDN, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
```

I'm not sure if this is correct as it was taken form soemthign specific for AD.
The problem seem to be $ldapDN. This is what i search for right? My groups "definition" is:

```
cn=User,ou=Profiles,ou=App_DEV,ou=ApplicationRights,O=MyCompany.COM
```

How can I do this check?

EDIT:

Here is my solution found with help of "Accepted Answer" and trial & error". I think the answer depends greatly on your specific system.

```
//This is the User group DN
$ldapDN = "cn=User,ou=Profiles,ou=App_DEV,ou=ApplicationRights,O=MyCompany.COM";
$filter = "(uniqueMember=uid=" . $uid . ",ou=Users,O=MYCOMPANY.COM)";
$attr = array('uniqueMember');
$result = ldap_search($ldapConnection, $ldapDN, $filter, $attr):
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $result);
ldap_unbind($ldapConnection);
return intval($entries["count"]) > 0;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Membership information is usually stored in the group - in the form of the 'member' or 'memberUid' attribute. 'member' represents the full DN (distinguished name) of the member object, and would look something like 'uid=username,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com'. In the case of memberUid, the value would simply be 'username'.

The way to figure out which is being used in your directory is to analyze a group using something like [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/).

In addition to the 'member' attribute, AD stores a memberOf attribute in the *user's* record which contains the DN of the group. But most directories don't do this, which is probably why your code isn't working.

What you're looking for is a filter like this:

```
// & means "And" the next sibling items: 
// so "find items that have the objectClass of group and a member whose DN is user_dn
(&(objectClass=group)(member=[user_dn]))
```

or

```
(&(objectClass=group)(memberUid=[user_uid]))
```

So in your case

```
$result = ldap_search(
    $ds,
    'dc=mycompany,dc=com', // The base from which to start your search. (could be an OU too, like 'ou=restricted,dc=mycompany,dc=com')
    '(&(objectClass=group)(member=uid=tom,ou=users,dc=mycompany,dc=com))'
);
```

Or if your groups go by memberUid, you would change the filter to

```
$filter = '(&(objectClass=group)(memberUid=username))';
```

$result should then contain a list of group records that have 'username' as a member.