# LDAP user authentification works with CN but not sAMAccountName

Tags: php, ldap

**What I got.**

I got a simple HTML login form, where username and password are passed to an ldap.php. I am able to successfully login, as soon as I use `cn=` instead of `sAMAccountName=`as a parameter. **For Example**, the user Mickey Mouse and `mmouse` as login does not work. Instead I need to login with `Mouse \, Mickey`. Which is pretty uncomfortable.

Do I need to authenticate, with an privilege account first and perform another bind with the wanted user afterwards?

**Whats the problem?**

If I replace `cn=` with `sAMAccountName=` I run into an ldap_bind error.

```
<?php
// LDAP Bind parameters
$ldap_dn = "sAMAccountName=".$_POST["username"].",OU=User of myCompany,OU=myCompany,DC=myDomain,DC=com";
$ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

$ldap_connection = ldap_connect("myCompany.com");

// Set LDAP protocol version
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
// Set LDAP returns to 0
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if (ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password))
    echo "Anmeldung erfolgreich";
else 
    echo "Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen";

?>
```

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to login users through LDAP? You need an account which is allowed to use LDAP. Compare it to a database: not all users in table `users` can connect to the database, you need a specific user which has been set up by an admin. Then you can connect to the database to access the table users. I dont see you checking if any user is in any group, im just seeing you wanting to connect. Does this help? Or are you searching for something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP LDAP: How to search if user is in group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487127/php-ldap-how-to-search-if-user-is-in-group)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal the problem with an dedicated service account is, that this account is maintaned too. Which automatically create the needs, to either develop a dedicated LDAP setting area for those application, where the password is set and encrypted or any kind of hardcoded possibility. Which is none sense. I don´t like both, which is the reason for my question.